# Transport taking longer time to pick up the content from transport root temporary folder in SDL Tridion R5.3

Tags: tridion, tridion-content-delivery

We are having performance issue with content publishing in SDL Tridion R5.3.

As soon as I publish content from CMS server I could see content folder being dropped to the transport temp folder C:\transportemp. However it takes almost 120-140 seconds for the transport to pick up this content and process it. Have you ever experienced similar issues. Is there any settings where we could decrease the transport listener service time? So that as soon system drops a content, transport would be kicked off and package would be send to publishing immediately.

I'm running my tests in test server of 2GB RAM, 2 CPUs with 2.53 GHZ speed. Transport rendering and deployment number of threads in CMS server SDL Tridion MMC snap in is 2
COM+ recycle setting is 512 MB.Transport root temporary folder given in SDL Tridion MMC snapin is C:\transporttemp\

I ran this test with a content folder tcm_0-423535-63560.Content of size 150KB.

Below is the statistics of the same test.

At 7.52.20 AM folder of size 109 KB dropped in to transport root package folder C:\transporttemp

folder remained stationary in C:\transporttemp  folder for 131 seconds.

transport started at [Debug 10-10-2012 07:54:31]
transport ended at [Debug 10-10-2012 07:54:41]

time taken for transport- 10 seconds

deployment started at [Debug 10-10-2012 07:54:32] 
deployment ended at [Debug 10-10-2012 07:54:39]
time taken for deployment- 7seconds

Appreciate your help on this. Thanks, KK

Comment: Are you certain that the publisher was finished with the package folder? Could it be that the folder is created when the publisher picks up the item from the queue, and the transport only starts when the publisher is finished?

Comment: Thanks Quirjin. No I'm not sure on that. Do you have an idea on how to verify that? Is there any logs which I can turn on for the same? Thanks,KK

Comment: Ok. I got it. Tcmpublisher log file. I'm verifying it now.

Comment: Hi Quirji, It is the publisher which takes a lot of time. Transport and deployment works like charm. I'm yet to figure out why publisher is taking long time. We have increased RAM from 2GB to 4 GB and that have helped us in 30 secs improvement in performance. Publisher is running in CMS server itself. I also have to figure if there is any delay in fetching data(from db server) to cms server by the publisher. Please let me know if you have any commnents on this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I thought so. Publishing performance varies completely depending on the templates. You may want to analyze them to see why they are so slow. If you use logging and run the template in the template builder, you can easily see what's causing the delay.

Comment: [Render engine] Emmbed the result of this rendered component presentation with a tcdl:ComponentPresentation link for component [tcm:12-49851] with template [tcm:12-25156-32][Render engine] Rendering took: 00:01:10.1690659. Above the log from publisher. However when I ran the template with the same component using template builder it took only 2.7 seconds. However rendering took a 1 min and 10 seconds. I guess template builder code is fine, its the rendering where I have troubles.I'm not sure where to look on to troubleshoot the rendering. I'm trying my best to resolve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you notice this behavior when you have lot of temp directory files and/or your transactions files did not get cleanup. You could check these folder locations for files/folders start with `tcm`.

You could setup some scheduled job to clean these folders on regular basis as part of your maintenance tasks.

The folders are typically

- TRIDION_HOME\bin\transactions on Publishing
- WINDOWS_HOME\temp  on CMS and Deployer as well

What type of transport mechanism you are using? `https`  `ftp` etc? Also, check if the package transfer is not taking time to upload to deployer (I do not know the package size, but 10 secs is not common for simple publishing packages).

Comment: Thanks Ram. I have checked these folders and they're empty.. I'm using HTTPs transport. I have figured out, its the publisher taking long time. Transport and deployment works like charm,but not publisher

Comment: OK. Is the template rendering taking lot of time? If yes, then consider checking checking if it is due to related components? You should also check your DB indexes and stats are up to date. If you run the template from TemplateBuilder what is time it is taking.

Comment: Hi Ram, Rendering took almost 1 minute and 41 seconds for one of the item in publishing. This is most expensive operation. Rest other renderings happened in <1 seconds.. However when I ran the template using template builder in client machine, it took only 2.7 seconds. So I guess the issue is completely with rendering. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this one. I'm trying my best now. Please let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

Comment: That kind of leads me to think the time it is taking might be trying to get the related components and render them during the publish. When you render from TemplateBuilder it does not resolve items for publishing, but when you publish it resolves all the related components as well. Could you check when you click publish from CMS GUI click on `See Items to Publish` and check How many items in the window.

Comment: Thanks Ram! I do see 30 items related to this component and is kind of messed up with localization and old version files. I'm trying to delete the older version files of this component and see if that could bring down the delay in publishing.